# Django Signals in celery

Tags: django, django-signals, celery

I have a task that runs in a Celerybeat instance. When that task is executed, it sometimes modifies a model object, which should fire off a post/pre_save signal, but it doesn't. The signal is not happening. I imagine this is due to Django's signals being synchronous while celery is doing it's thing on a different server in a different thread in a different universe. Is there a simple way to still get those signals to fire while they're being ran in celery?

Answer (score 21):

Django signals are local, which means that the signal handler must be registered in the worker as well.

If your signal handler is connected in e.g. `models.py`, then you need to import that
in `tasks.py` to make sure it's also connected in the worker.

Alternatively you can specify additional modules the worker should import using
the `CELERY_IMPORTS` setting:

```
CELERY_IMPORTS = ("myapp.handlers", )
```

or the `-I` argument to celeryd.

```
$ python manage.py celeryd -I myapp.handlers
```