# django not receiving signals from celery

Tags: django, celery, django-signals

I have a model called

```
class Vcf(models.Model):
    ...
```

And I have a post_save signal receiver for this model

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Vcf)
def vcf_post_save(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    group = Group.objects.get(name='name')
    if created:
        assign_perm('view_vcf', instance.user, instance)
        assign_perm('view_vcf', group, instance)
```

I have a view function where users can fill out a form and this will start a celery task. Which calls a function `get_results` which in turn calls another function `create_vcf_model`

```
@shared_task
def do_stuff(user_id, run_id, config):
    ...other stuff...
    get_results(run_id)


get results(run_id):
    ...other stuff...
    create_vcf_model(run_id, vcf_path)

create_vcf_model(run_id, vcf_path):
    vcf, created = Vcf.objects.get_or_create()
```

Problem is here. I am guessing because create function is called from a celery task django is not receiving the signal?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920174/django-signals-in-celery